# Communication between LAN and Microcontroller

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serial-port, lan

so I have a kinda strange problem. I'm using LAN for the communication with a microcontroller. Everything was working perfect. Meaning: I can send and receive data. For receiving data I'm using a simple method, which is `Thread.sleep(1)` in a `for` loop in which I keep checking `client.GetStream().DataAvailable` for true while `client` is a `TcpClient`
Now, with one process I have to send and receive to the microcontroller with a higher Baud rate. I was using 9600 for all other operations and everythingwas fine. Now with 115200 `client.GetStream().DataAvailable`seems to always have the value `false`.
What could be the problem?

PS: Another way to communicate with the microcontroller (all chosen by user) is serial communication. This is still working fine with the higher Baud rate.

Here is a code snippet:

```
using (client = new TcpClient(IP_String, LAN_Port))`
                    {
                        client.SendTimeout = 200;
                        client.ReceiveTimeout = 200;
                        stream = client.GetStream();
                        .
                        .
                        bool OK = false;
                        stream.Write(ToSend, 0, ToSend.Length);
                        for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
                        {   
                            if (stream.DataAvailable)
                            {
                                OK = true;
                                break;
                            }
                                Thread.Sleep(1);
                        }
                        .
                        .
                    }
```

EDIT:
While monitoring the communication with a listing device I realized that the bits actually arrive and that the device actually answers. The one and only problem seem that the `DataAvailable` flag is not being raised. I should probably find another way to check data availability. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to think of things I've seen that act this way...

I've seen serial chips that say they'll do 115,200, but actually won't. See what happens if you drop the baud rate one notch. Either way you'll learn something.

Some microcontrollers "bit-bang" the serial port by having the CPU raise and lower the data pin and essentially go through the bits, banging 1 or 0 onto the serial pin. When a byte comes in, they read it, and do the same thing.
This does save money (no serial chip) but it is an absolute hellish nightmare to actually get working reliably. 115,200 may push a bit-banger too hard.

This might be a subtle microcontroller problem. Say you have a receiving serial chip which asserts a pin when a byte has come in, usually something like DRQ* for "Data Request" (the * in DRQ* means a 0-volt is "we have a byte" condition) (c'mon, people, a * isn't always a pointer:-).  Well, DRQ* requests an interrupt, the firmware & CPU interrupt, it reads the serial chip's byte, and stashes it into some handy memory buffer. Then it returns from interrupt.

A problem can emerge if you're getting data very fast. Let's assume data has come in, serial chip got a byte ("#1" in this example), asserted DRQ*, we interrupted, the firmware grabs and stashes byte #1, and returns from interrupt. All well and good. But think what happens if another byte comes winging in *while* that first interrupt is still running. The serial chip now has byte #2 in it, so it again asserts the already-asserted DRQ* pin. The interrupt of the first byte completes. What happens?
You hang.

This is because it's the -edge- of DRQ*, physically going from 5V to 0V, that actually causes the CPU interrupt. On the second byte, DRQ* started at 0 and was set to 0. So DRQ* is (still) asserted, but there's no -edge- to tell the interrupt hardware/CPU that another byte is waiting. And now, of course, all the rest of the incoming data is also dropped.

See why it gets worse at higher speeds? The interrupt routine is fielding data more and more quickly, and typically doing circular I/O buffer calculations within the interrupt handler, and it must be fast and efficient, because fast input can push the interrupt handler to where a full new byte comes in before the interrupt finishes.

This is why it's a good idea to check DRQ* during the interrupt handler to see if another byte (#2) is already waiting (if so, just read it in, to clear the serial chip's DRQ*, and stash the byte in memory right then), or use "level triggering" for interrupts, not "edge triggering". Edge triggering definitely has good uses, but you need to watch out for this.

I hope this is helpful. It sure took me long enough to figure it out the first time. Now I take great care on stuff like this.

Good luck, let me know how it goes.

- thanks,
  Dave Small

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Dave. It sure took a while putting your idea into text. Nevertheless I'm not sure about this because as I said before I have two separate connectors on the device which houses the microcontroller, one is serial and the other is LAN. While with the serial communication everything works, the `client.GetStream().DataAvailable` flag never rises while using LAN. So my guess would be that the microcontroller itself is not to blame, right? PS: I must point out that I didn't program the microcontroller. What I'm trying to do is to realize the communication with a PC.